# Debugging Python Docker in VS Code

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am having an issue with the debugger I can't quite wrap my head around.  My problem is: when running my code in the container the changes won't persist. (I have my volumes declared)

My set up is the following: I created a python virtual env and then created a python file with the following (just write a file to disk).  I then used the docker command via the tutorial to add all my docker files.  It creates a docker-compose and a docker-compose.debug.  To both compose files i add a volume so my file will persist.  If i execute docker-compose up the file will get executed and i see a test.txt file arrive in my directory.  However, if I run through the debugger, it seems to disregard my volume declarative and then my file doesn't appear in my host directory.  Do you have any ideas what i am doing wrong?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python

**Test.py**

```
import datetime

text_file = open("test.txt", "w")
text_file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
text_file.close()
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  test:
    image: test
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}:/app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.debug.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  test:
    image: test
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}:/app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python /tmp/debugpy --wait-for-client --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 test.py"
    ports:
      - 5678:5678
```

**dockerfile**

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install pip requirements
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something that will more or less do what i want.  Using the below as a template, i created a remote attach profile that attaches to any process on port 5678.  Then, be it my web app or just a normal python file i opened up port 5678 on the container, added pvtsd, and then instructed whichever file i wanted to debug to wait for an attachment.  Seems to work pretty well.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python